# Table - After deleting some rows, the next rows become/stay selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I drop some rows in my table, the next rows become/stay selected.

In my `state` I have `selectedStudents` and `tableData`. The `selectedStudents` are all selected index in my table.

When I click on delete button.. the follow code remove all rows in my `tableData` and all values in `selectedStudents`.

```
let diff = _.remove(this.state.tableData, (it, idx) => !~this.state.selectedStudents.indexOf(idx))
this.setState({ tableData: diff, selectedStudents: [] })
```

**The problem** is that the rows are deleted but the next rows are selected, and I don't know why

[image]
[See full image with states details here](https://i.imgur.com/h5Tg1X1.gifv)

This is the full code for this component... or [check in WebPack bin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kgkah1WAylqlDFHruUL)

```
export default React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selectedStudents: [],
            tableData: [
                { name: 'John Smith' },
                { name: 'Randal White' },
                { name: 'Stephanie Sanders' },
                { name: 'Steve Brown' },
                { name: 'Joyce Whitten' },
                { name: 'Samuel Roberts' },
                { name: 'Adam Moore' }
            ]
        }
    },

    // Methods
    _onStudentSelected (selected) {
        let selectedObjs = []
        if (_.isArray(selected)) { // Multiples selections
            selectedObjs.push(...selected)
        } else if (_.isNumber(selected)) { // One Selection
            selectedObjs.push(selected)
        } else if (_.isString(selected) && selected === 'all') { // Select all elements
            selectedObjs.push(...this.state.tableData.map((it, idx) => idx))
        } // None selected

        this.setState({ selectedStudents: selectedObjs })
    },

    _onClickDeleteStudent () {
        let diff = _.remove(this.state.tableData, (it, idx) =>
            !~this.state.selectedStudents.indexOf(idx))

        this.setState({ tableData: diff, selectedStudents: [] })
    },


    render: function() {
        return (
        <Table fixedHeader multiSelectable onRowSelection={this._onStudentSelected}>
            <TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false}>
                {this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => (
                    <TableRow key={row.name} selected={this.state.selectedStudents.indexOf(index) !== -1}>
                        <TableRowColumn>
                            <TextField value={row.name} hintText='Name' />
                        </TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>
                            <TextField hintText='Password' type='password' />
                        </TableRowColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter adjustForCheckbox>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableRowColumn>
                        <RaisedButton label='Delete' onClick={this._onClickDeleteStudent}
                                      disabled={this.state.selectedStudents.length <= 0} />
                    </TableRowColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
        </Table>
        );
    }
});
```

---

**Versions**

Package     | Version
----------- | ------------------------------------
material-ui | ^0.17.1
react       | ^15.4.2
Browser     | Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

**ADDED**

Was reported as a bug on [issue 6496](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/6496)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current stable version 16.7, onRowSelection(indices) of Table component, indices does not reflect the right state after deleting last rows. You may checkout the fixed version via: npm install --save material-ui@next, but it is still under testing so far. Cheers.

Edited:
M.Quan changed the source code and it works okay for me by the way.
Please see https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/6006

"I found the cause of the error at line 131 in
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Table/TableBody.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.allRowsSelected !== nextProps.allRowsSelected) {
        if (!nextProps.allRowsSelected) {
            this.setState({
              selectedRows: [],
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                selectedRows: this.calculatePreselectedRows(nextProps),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When i change that code with the code in version 0.16.6. It worked with me!

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.allRowsSelected && !nextProps.allRowsSelected) {
        this.setState({
            selectedRows: this.state.selectedRows.length > 0 ?
            [this.state.selectedRows[this.state.selectedRows.length - 1]] : [],
        });
        // TODO: should else be conditional, not run any time props other than allRowsSelected change?
    } else {
        this.setState({
            selectedRows: this.calculatePreselectedRows(nextProps),
        });
    }
}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

Here a simplified modern refactored version of your example :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Table from 'material-ui/Table/Table'
import TableBody from 'material-ui/Table/TableBody'
import TableHeader from 'material-ui/Table/TableHeader'
import TableFooter from 'material-ui/Table/TableFooter'
import TableHeaderColumn from 'material-ui/Table/TableHeaderColumn'
import TableRow from 'material-ui/Table/TableRow'
import TableRowColumn from 'material-ui/Table/TableRowColumn'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField/TextField'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton/RaisedButton'

export default class MyTable extends Component {

  state = {
    selectedStudents: [],
    tableData: [
      { id: 0, name: 'John Smith' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Randal White' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Stephanie Sanders' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Steve Brown' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Joyce Whitten' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Samuel Roberts' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Adam Moore' }
    ]
  }

  // Methods
  _onStudentSelected = (selected) => {
    let selectedStudents = selected === 'all'// Select all elements
      ? [...this.state.tableData].map(({id}) => id)
      : selected

    console.log('selected', selected,
                '\nSelected students', selectedStudents)

    this.setState({selectedStudents})
  }

  _onClickDeleteStudent = () => {
    let tableData = this.state.tableData.filter(({id}) =>
      !this.state.selectedStudents.includes(id)
    )

    this.setState({tableData, selectedStudents: []}, () => {
      console.log('After delete', this.state.tableData,
                '\nthis.state.selectedStudents', this.state.selectedStudents)
    })
  }

  render () {
    console.debug('rendered selectedStudents', this.state.selectedStudents)
    const isSelected = id => {
      let result = this.state.selectedStudents.includes(id)
      console.log('id', id, 'result', result)
      return result
    }
    return (
      <Table fixedHeader multiSelectable enableSelectAll onRowSelection={this._onStudentSelected}>
        <TableHeader>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Password</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false}>
          {this.state.tableData.map(({id, name}) => (
            <TableRow key={id} selected={isSelected(id)}>
              <TableRowColumn>
                <TextField value={name} hintText='Name' />
              </TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>
                <TextField hintText='Password' type='password' />
              </TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
        <TableFooter adjustForCheckbox>
          <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn>
              <RaisedButton label='Delete' onTouchTap={this._onClickDeleteStudent}
                            disabled={!this.state.selectedStudents.length} />
            </TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope it helps despite it not solving your issue. You should raise an issue in Material-UI repo.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It would be very nice of you to provide some context or explanation for your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

please use onTouchTap instead of onClick

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15810119)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot This is an attempt to answer the question. Please read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).